# How i can do several input via rarun2?

Tags: radare2

How can i do several input via rarun2, if my program requares two input?
[image]

I try this:

[image]

Comment: have you tried with `stdin` set as a file or pty?

Comment: This does not work

Comment: add the source code for your program that reads this data

Comment: I cant change program, i have only elf file. I need to do several input via rarun2.

Comment: So just attach this binary so I can provide you with the details that will work with it.

Comment: I think that it would be nicer if you didn't use images for textual information.

Answer (score 1):

To type two inputs of

> aaa

as expected in your first example, write

```
#!/usr/bin/rarun2
stdin="aaa\naaa\n"
```

in a file `script.rr2`. Then do `radare2 -r script.rr2 -d [your program to debug]`.